# Output an array into a text file line by line

Tags: ruby, file, text

Using this code:

```
open('myfile.txt', 'w') { |f|
  f.puts response
}
```

I can output array json response into a text file, but it won't open as it has one continuous line, and the text seems to write over itself. How can I get this so it would be on each line?

response as a hash = (done through Awesome Print)

```
[
    [0] [
        [0] 51.5366586,
        [1] -1.7846845,
        [2] 1.0
    ]
]
```

I've tried a few things but it just wont seem to work!

Thanks

Comment: You should open the file with `a` instead of `w` if you want to append.

Comment: ahhh! okay I can get it working with the a not w - thanks!!

Comment: feel free to delete your question, it won't be useful to anybody else.

Comment: no it didn't i have edited to show reponse

Comment: Based on the text of your question, I'm guessing you're not doing what you think you're doing. Are you sure `response` is an array? Or is it just the string representation of an array in JSON? You need to convert the JSON string into an actual ruby array "on purpose" -- it doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: okay i have converted my json response into a hash will post above

Comment: does that make more sense now?